# Use Google Charts in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I am trying to use google charts in an ReactJS application. I do not want to use "[react-google-charts](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts)".
I already searched the whole internet and this is my current code...
In my `index.html` I do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=
{'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':
['corechart']}]}"></script>
```

And my component to use the chart looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {MainViewHeader} from './MainViewHeader';
import TouristService from '../../services/TouristService';
import Util from '../../services/Util';

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

export class MainView extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            touristInfos: [],
            touristInfosHeader: []
        };
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.renderGoogleTable());
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let touristInfos = TouristService.getAllTouristInfos();
        touristInfos.then(
            info =>
                this.setState({
                    touristInfos: Util.getResults(info)
                })
        );
        //this.renderGoogleTable();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.renderGoogleTable();
    }

    renderGoogleTable(){
        let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(this.state.touristInfos);

        let table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="search-and-overview">
                <MainViewHeader />
                <div className="mid-region">
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="problem-list">
                            <div id="table_div"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have no clue where or how to use the `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(myGraphDrawingFunction)` so I tried this version I found on a stackoverflow post for using google charts in angular.
I need to use `this` in the `renderGoogleTable` function. So when I use the "regular setOnLoadCallback way" I cannot use `this` anymore.

My chrome dev tools throw this error

```
MainView.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: google.visualization.Table is not a constructor
    at MainView.renderGoogleTable (MainView.js:36)
    at MainView.js:15
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: You could pass `this` as a parameter to `renderGoogleTable` or `bind` the function.

Answer (score 1):

In react, an understanding of component life cycle is one thing you mostly need. In jQuery, for instance, we use the `ready` function to know when the DOM has been fully loaded. In react, the equivalent is componentDidMount.

So, you can declare your `setOnLoadCallback` in the componentDidMount.

Also, remember to declare your methods in the constructor and bind `this`.

NOTE: You can also do things like this in componentWillMount (update >> componentWillMount is deprecated), but in this very case, it will throw an error since the div `table_div` is not yet loaded at this point.

ie `this.renderGoogleTable = this.renderGoogleTable.bind(this)`

You can read more about component life cycle here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle